# Scroll HorizontalScrollView in Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter, horizontalscrollview

I have a sticky-header `Adapter` with `horizontalScrollView` as the child as shown below. When the view "A3" is selected and double tapped, I want the selected box to scroll to the purple square.

I have used `horizontalScrollView` in other cases and I would scroll the view using

`horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(191*position, 0);`

But it is not the case in Adapter. Great if anyone would share a solution to this issue.

[image]

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "But it is not the case in Adapter."

Comment: Now the horizontal scroll view is the child in the adapter, and then the scrollview would no longer use the "smoothScrollTo" function